# Directive inside ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i manipulate (get specific directive) inside a ng repeat?

Example:

I have my directive

```
<actionbar>
  <action_button ng-repeat="actionButton in actionsButtons"></action_button>
</actionbar>
```

Where  and  are diferents directive, which actionbar has many action buttons or just one.

I need to get specific directive and manipulate values from there. Like: Let's imagine that I have a array which will generate two action button. I will make an ng-repeat and compile to HTML. Now I need when I click in first action button If the second is active deactive the second one and the same reaction for the first one button.

How can I manipulate and get specific directive inside ng-repeat?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but what you seem to be asking about is exactly what directives are designed to prohibit.  You are likely thinking about the directives in the wrong way if you are trying to modify their HTML output; instead, you should be setting properties in the directive's controller, and responding to the value changes.  Have the `action_button` deactivate itself, not something else deactivate it.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I must need a list of action button and this when I click in one affect the other one. But this is unclear for me (how can I do when I click in one action_button deactive the other one), because I have just one controller (ActionbuttonController). So I need to get specific directive and active or deactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is communicate between the different directives inside the ng-repeat, you could create a factory (factories and services only instantiate once) which will be shared across all the directives. Then inside that directive you can specify the information to use. For example if you have 10 elements inside the ng-repeat, and only one can be active at a time, you can create a getter and setter inside the factory that will retrieve/set the ID or value of the active element. And in the directives you just have to call that function.

Comment: But this will affect all of them. Because I don't know how to set in specific directive element because they are just an array I don't have any index or something like that.

Comment: But you can create a function called getIndex inside the factory which will return the value of the index + 1. In the directive you will set the property, so you will have a different index for each one.

Comment: I'm not so sure if I really understand. Could you give me an simple example?

Comment: Yes, here you have an example that I made: 
http://jsbin.com/wufeqitubi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Rodrigo. This help me but this cause a new issue. I update just update your JSBin: http://jsbin.com/jidewa/edit?html,js,output .Now you can see if I add a click event to first element, this will propagate to every directive elements. If I want to make active and deactive It's will propagate to all directive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110073/discussion-between-rodrigo-juarez-and-leonan-luppi).